# C++ default implementation of stack and queue

Tags: c++, c++11

In **C++ Primer 5th**, it says that the default implementation of `stack` and `queue` is `deque`.

I'm wondering why they don't use `list`? Stack and Queue doesn't support random access, always operate on both ends, therefore `list` should be the most intuitive way to implement them, and `deque`, which support random access (with constant time) is somehow not necessary.

Could anyone explain the reason behind this implementation?

Comment: My first guess would be that linked lists can have terrible real-world performance due to pointer chasing (and having to allocate new memory for every single element). But I don't know whether that's the real reason.

Comment: Good question. You can make a stack and a queue using an array or a list. These are known as "array based" or "list based" implementations. Ofcourse you can do this with other data structures aswell. Not exactly what your asking but an important point.

Comment: I'm surprised the default for stack is not std::vector actually.  It seems like the contiguous memory would be useful in that case.

Comment: @BenjaminJones *The C++ Programming Language*, in at least some editions, states (incorrectly) that `vector` is the default for `stack`. So apparently Stroustrup agrees with you. :)

Comment: My thoughts on the subject: https://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/letter-the-fourth/

Comment: @BenjaminJones "I'm surprised the default for stack is not std::vector actually". - for deque: "A call to resize with a bigger size does not invalidate any references to elements of the deque." may because of this - no need to reallocate memory for and reconstruct already added objects.

Comment: On the other hand, `list` supports constant time insertion and deletion for middle elements, which is somehow not necessary.

Answer (score 10):

With `std::list` as underlying container each `std::stack::push` does a memory allocation. Whereas `std::deque` allocates memory in chunks and can reuse its spare capacity to avoid the memory allocation.

With small elements the storage overhead of list nodes can also become significant. E.g. `std::list<int>` node size is 24 bytes (on a 64-bit system), with only 4 bytes occupied by the element - at least 83% storage overhead.

Answer (score 4):

the main reason is because deque is faster than the list in average for front and back insertions and deletions

deque is faster because memory is allocated by chunks were as list need allocation on each elements and allocation are costly operations.

[benchmark](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2017/05/cpp-containers-benchmark-vector-list-deque-plf-colony.html)

Answer (score 4):

I think the question should be asked the other way around: Why use a list if you can use an array?

The list is more complicated: More allocations, more resources (for storing pointers) and more work to do (even if it is all in constant time). On the other hand, the main property for preferring lists is also not relevant to stacks and queues: constant-time random insertion and deletion.

Comment: Well, you probably shouldn't use an array, since that doesn't provide worst-case constant time complexity for insertion/deletion. Are you suggesting that the implementation of a deque is simpler than that of a linked list?

Comment: @Sneftel Valid point, this is why deque does not guarantee continous storage of elements.

Comment: `std::array` doesn't provide insertion/deletion *at all*. `std::vector` does, and hints at the slowness of prepending by lacking `push_front`

Comment: @Sneftel In the context of `stack` and `queue`, there are no insertions/deletions anywhere but at the ends.

Comment: The constant time is kind of a red herring for `std::list`, as *constant* here means *always expensive*. The advantage of a list is that the objects stay put once inserted, but that also happens for deque if you only operate on the ends.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin `std::vector` has worst-case linear complexity for both front- and back-insertion, and for front deletion.

Comment: @Sneftel that's disingenuous, `std::vector` has *amortised* constant back-insertion.

Comment: @Caleth ...which may be acceptable for a given user. But if you're exposing something as simple and with as well known "normal" complexity as a stack, you don't want to violate the normal complexity guarantees *by default*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare the sequence containers:

`std::array` is right out, it doesn't change size.

`std::list` optimises for iterator non-invalidation, allows insertion at known positions, and lacks random access. It has O(N) space overhead, with a large constant, and it has bad cache locality.

`std::forward_list` is an even more crippled `list` with smaller space overhead

`std::deque` optimises for appending or prepending, at the expense of not being contiguous. It has O(N) space overhead, with a smaller constant, and it has mediocre cache locality.

`std::vector` optimises for access speed, at the expense of insertion / removal anywhere but the end. It has O(1) space overhead, and the great cache locality.

So what does this mean for stack and queue?

`std::stack` only requires operations at one end. `std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::list` all provide the necessary operations

`std::queue` requires operations at both ends. `std::deque` and `std::list` are the only candidates.

The choice of `std::deque` as the default is then one of consistency, as `std::vector` is generally better for `std::stack`, but inapplicable for `std::queue`.

Note that `std::priority_queue`, whilst named similar to `std::queue`, is actually more akin to `std::stack` in requiring only modification at one end. It also benefits more from the raw access speed of `std::vector`, maintaining the heap invariant.